# How to set a theme on a compound custom view

Tags: android

I am trying to set a theme on a custom view made up of other views with the help of the `theme` attribute and some custom view attributes.
The code looks something like this:

**IconTextView.java**

```
public class IconTextView extends LinearLayout {

    public IconTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, 0);
    }

    public IconTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, 0);
    }

    public IconTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void init(Context context, int defStyleAttr) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_icon_text, this, true);
    }
}
```

**attrs_icon_text_view.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="IconTextViewTheme">
    <attr name="textViewStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="iconStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**view_icon_text.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        style="?iconStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <TextView
        style="?textViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:text="Hello"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">      
    </style>

    <style name="Custom.IconTextView" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Custom.Test" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="textViewStyle">@style/Special.IconTextView</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**layout_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <IconTextView
        app:theme="@style/Custom.Test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Unfortunately, this only works in the Android Studio preview if the theme is selected through the preview's theme selector. It does not work with the `theme` attribute.

Shouldn't the `theme` attribute apply the styles contained in the theme to the view and its children? 
Is this even possible or should I just apply the theme to the entire activity?

Answer (score 1):

For people like me that want to know a possible solution to this problem.
You can do something like this:

**attrs.xml**

```
<!-- Define your attribute that you can use in a main theme -->
<attr name="iconTextViewTheme" format="reference"/>

<declare-styleable name="IconTextViewTheme">
    <attr name="textViewStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="iconStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">  
        <!-- Define what style you want to use for this component in AppTheme -->
        <!-- If you have multiple themes, you can customize this per theme -->    
        <item name="iconTextViewTheme">@style/myCustomIconTextViewTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myCustomIconTextViewTheme">
        <item name="textViewStyle">@style/insertYourCustomTextViewStyleHere</item>
        <item name="iconStyle">@style/insertYourCustomImageViewStyleHere</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**view_icon_text.xml**

```
<!-- Apply the style with android:theme using an attribute applies the style to child views -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="?attr/iconTextViewTheme">

    <ImageView
        style="?attr/iconStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <TextView
        style="?attr/textViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:text="Hello"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is described here with couple of alternatives

https://gyula-juhasz.com/blog/styling-composite-views-in-android-part-1/

Comment: Link is broken.